# row height is not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, rows, row-height

I have created an html stuff using bootstrap 2.3.2 css. The html will be having four rows with different height such as for the first row it will 10%, second row - 20%, third row - 40% and the fourth row - 40% respetively. The html is rendering  but the problem is that the height of each row is not displaying correctly.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5myr9k5/)**

**html**

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="row1">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">content1</div>
      <div class="span6">content1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">content2</div>
      <div class="span6">content2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">content3</div>
      <div class="span4">content3</div>
      <div class="span4">content3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row4">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3">content4</div>
      <div class="span3">content4</div>
      <div class="span3">content4</div>
      <div class="span3">content4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.row1 {
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
}

.row2 {
  height: 20%;
  background: yellow;
}

.row3 {
  height: 40%;
  background: orange;
}
.row4 {
  height: 40%;
  background: violet;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: height never works that way !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use a percentage based height, *all* ancestors must have a defined height.

Add this to your example:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtdw280w/2/)

If your elements are heavily nested, a better solution may be to use the following instead:

```
#content {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ayepo0m/3/)

Comment: if the content of the row exceeds the height how we can bring the vertical scrollbar

Comment: By adding `overflow: auto;` to your row

Comment: I mean not for the entire row, for each column, when I added the `overflow:auto` I got like this https://jsfiddle.net/6ayepo0m/1/

Comment: Please open a new question. That's entirely unrelated to this one.